# WP_Query not "resetting" when AJAX filter params become empty

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

This question was [originally posted in wordpress.stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/386079/500-error-when-ajax-filter-params-are-empty-for-wp-query-tax-query), but deemed to be off-topic for some reason, so I'm posting here per the suggestion in the ruling comment.

I've created an AJAX taxonomy(`product_cat`) filter that's used on my WooCommerce product archive page (`archive-product.php`). The page loads the normal WooCommerce shop loop onload:

```
woocommerce_product_loop_start();

if (wc_get_loop_prop('total')) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();

        /**
         * Hook: woocommerce_shop_loop.
         *
         * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 10
         */
        do_action('woocommerce_shop_loop');

        wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
    }
}

woocommerce_product_loop_end();
```

That page loads correctly, showing all products. The filter also works great. It filters one or more taxonomies correctly.

The problem is when I *uncheck* all the checkboxes. I want it to clear any filters and show all products again. Instead, I currently get an error:

```
POST .../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500
```

The relevant product filter js:

```
function handleFilterCheckboxesChange(event) {
    const data = {
        action: 'wpf_update_products',
        filters: get_current_filters()
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: data,
        success: function (res) {
            console.log("AJAX Success: ", data.filters);
            // > ["example_category_slug"]
            $('.products').html(res);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.error("AJAX Error: ", data.filters);
            // > []
        }
    });

    $(document.body).trigger('post-load');
}

function get_current_filters() {
    const checkboxes = $('.product-cat-filter-checkbox').get();
    let checked = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            checked.push(checkboxes[i].id);
        };
    }
    return checked;
}
```

The server-side action:

```
function wpf_update_products() {
    
    $filter_terms = $_POST['filters'];
    
    $args = [
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 20,
        'post_status'    => 'publish',
    ];

    // I expect the next line to check for empty filter terms and "reset"/skip this tax_query, but I still get a 500 error
    if ($filter_terms !== null && isset($filter_terms) && $filter_terms !== '' && !empty($filter_terms)) {
        $args['tax_query'][] = [
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $_POST['filters']
        ];
    }

    $ajax_query = new WP_Query($args);
    $response = '';

    if ($ajax_query->have_posts()) {
        ob_start();
        while ($ajax_query->have_posts()) : $ajax_query->the_post();
            $response .= wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
        endwhile;
        $output = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        echo __('Sorry, there are no products that fit your query.', 'wpf');
    }
    echo $output;
    die();
}
```

...hooked from the same class:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_wpf_update_products', array($this, 'wpf_update_products'));
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_wpf_update_products', array($this, 'wpf_update_products'));
```

When I var_dump the query on successful filtering, it correctly shows the added tax_query, but I'm unable to dump the query on unsuccessful [empty] filtering because the server responds with 500.

Can't figure out why it's returning the error if I'm handling the empty `$_POST['filters']` on the server side. Can anyone see what I'm missing?

**UPDATE:** I added an else to the server-side query, and was able to get around the 500 error. The updated `if` statement to set the filter query args is:

```
if ($filter_terms !== null && isset($filter_terms) && $filter_terms !== '' && !empty($filter_terms)) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = [
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $filter_terms
    ];
} else {
    $args['tax_query'][] = [
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'
    ];
}
```

Now, the query tries to run, but I get the `'Sorry, there are no products that fit your query.'` statement because no posts were found. `WP_Query` doesn't seem to like a `tax_query` with only the `taxonomy` set. I var_dumped the query and see that the `tax_query` is filled correctly with the three args when a filter is checked:

```
'tax_query' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          ...
```

...and when all filters become unchecked, the `tax_query` has the one `'taxonomy' => 'product_cat'` arg:

```
'tax_query' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
```

I just can't seem to clear the `tax_query` if filters is empty. With the original code—no `else` statement if filters is empty—I just got the 500 error, but even if my else statement sets the `tax_query` completely empty like so: `$args['tax_query'][] = []`, it still throws the 500 error. Why doesn't WP fall back to the rest of the original query if `tax_query` is empty?

And finally, I also tried setting the query args manually to all possible taxonomy terms like so:

```
if ($filter_terms !== null && isset($filter_terms) && $filter_terms !== '' && !empty($filter_terms)) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = [
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $filter_terms
    ];
} else {
    $all_terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'fields' => 'slugs'));
    $args['tax_query'][] = [
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $all_terms
    ];
}
```

...but I just get the 500 error again :/
Dumping `$all_terms` gives me this, a list of all terms that contain any products:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string 'bakeware' (length=8)
  1 => string 'cookware' (length=8)
  2 => string 'cutlery-kitchen-tools' (length=21)
  3 => string 'linens' (length=6)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the `$filter_terms` variable being set within the scope of your  `wpf_update_products()` function. If I'm understanding the intent of your code correctly, try the following:

```
// I expect the next line to check for empty filter terms and "reset"/skip this tax_query, but I still get a 500 error
if ( ! empty( $_POST['filters'] ) ) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = [
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $_POST['filters']
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And I apologize. I have `$filter_terms` being set in my actual code, but it didn't get transferred over to SO when I was writing the question. I've updated my code above. You can see that I had the `! empty($_POST['filters'])` check for that reason also. Any other ideas?

Comment: I have a couple of hunches here. Assuming you're on PHP 7+, try setting `$filter_terms` like this:

`$filter_terms = $_POST['filter_terms'] ?? NULL;`

It's a long shot, but your server could be triggering 500 errors when a  PHP notice is triggered.

If that doesn't work, please do a `print_r( $filter_terms );` when no checkboxes are checked and send me the output.

Comment: Sorry - typo in the last comment. `$filter_terms = $_POST['filters'] ?? NULL;`

Comment: So, it didn't seem to work. With the `?? null;` you suggested, I still get this print_r'd when a filter is checked: `Array ( [0] => linens )` but I'm not able to `print_r($filter_terms);` when unchecked because the server returns the 500 error still. And yes I'm on PHP 7.4.1.

Comment: I've updated my question above with some new attempts/discoveries.

Comment: The 500 error is likely coming from the incorrectly formatted tax query when there aren’t any checkboxes checked. After your print_r($filter_terms); add in a die();  this will prevent the query from executing and allow us to see what values are in $filter_terms.

Comment: Also, try setting define( ‘WP_DEBUG’, TRUE ); within your wp-config.php. This will tell WordPress to display the actual error that is happening instead of just a generic 500 error.

Comment: Printing/var_dumping `$filter_terms` is null, as expected. I've updated my code in the question above. I'll have to keep investigating, and will report back if I solve the problem. Thanks again for looking into it!

Comment: Please send the output of the 500 error with WP_DEBUG enabled.

Comment: Unfortunately, even with WP_DEBUG enabled, all I get is the aforementioned console error: `POST .../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500`

Comment: With WP_DEBUG enabled, you'll want to go the Network tab within your browser tools. Find the ajax request that is returning the 500 error (it should be red) and then click on the "Response" tab within the pane that opens up - this should provide us with some additional information on what the actual error is.

Comment: Yea, the response is a pretty unhelpful: `<p>There has been a critical error on this website.</p><p><a href="https://wordpress.org/support/article/faq-troubleshooting/">Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.</a></p>`

Comment: Nothing is ever easy! If you can access your server logs, the error message should show up in there. You'll want to look for entries related to PHP errors.

Comment: No it is not :) I’m developing using Local by WPEngine, and those server logs are empty as well unfortunately, which is why I resorted to SO. Been trying to figure out why Local isn’t logging also. I’m away at the moment but will have to try to diagnose that and/or try testing on a live dev server when I’m back.